# Filtering items in .data() object by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute, jquery-filter

EDIT: forgot the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMBPP/30/)

I've got an SVG image consisting of many paths/shapes, each contained in a `<g>` element with an `id`. To keep things simple, I've limited my example to two shapes.

I've also got a series of `<div>`s - representing several colors - which have a `data-attribute` that can match an SVG shape `<g>` id. So:

```
<svg width="428" height="230" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g id="square">
  <rect height="91" width="91" y="68.5" x="82.5"/>
 </g>
 <g id="circle">
  <ellipse ry="48" rx="48" id="svg_2" cy="111.5" cx="295.5"/>
 </g>
</svg>

<div class="colors" data-square="5" data-circle="0">Red</div>
<div class="colors" data-square="1" data-circle="3">Blue</div>
<div class="colors" data-square="0" data-circle="9">Green</div>
```

On clicking a `.color` `<div>`, I'd like to:

1. Store all the attributes (keys and values) in an object (done),
2. **Filter out any attributes less than 1 (the part I can't figure out)**
3. Then add a class (`.active`) to any svg `<g>` elements with an `id` that matches the attribute key (done, without the filtering).

Here's my jQuery, along with my commented-out attempt to filter the `data()` object:

```
var shapes = $('svg g');

$('.colors').click(function () {
    //remove active class from all shapes
    $(shapes).attr("class", "");
    //store data attributes
    var colortotals = $(this).data();
    //filter attributes greater than 0
    //var colortotals = $(this).data().filter(function() {
      //return $(this) > "0";
    //});
    //add active class to any shape with id matching an attribute key
    $.each(colortotals, function(key, value) {
      alert(key + ": " + value);
      $(shapes).filter('#' + key).attr("class", "active");
    });

});
```

Comment: calling `$(this).data().filter(function{...})` will, fail, since result from 'data()' is not a jQuery wrapped object and therefore you can not call jQuery methods over it. You should do $(colortotals). But also filter is not the best choice here, since it would give you whole object:`{circle: 0, square: 5}`. Check the solution from Jonathan below, that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$.each(colortotals, function(key, value) {
    if (Number(value) > 0) {

      $(shapes).filter('#' + key).attr("class", "active");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rMBPP/31/

Sorry if I didn't understand the question correctly

Comment: Jonathan, this is perfect - thank you! I realized how confusing the question was after I posted it; I wasn't sure anyone would care enough to wade through the wording. I can see from your answer that I was using `.filter()` incorrectly.